# Quasar, PouchDB error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v1' of undefined at eval (wrapper.mjs?c9e8:2)

Tags: pouchdb, quasar-framework

How to solve this error?
I used Quasar-cli to create and then added puchdb.

Added pouchdb to quasar app:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
```

And get this error:

app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:263 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v1' of undefined
at eval (wrapper.mjs?c9e8:2)
at Module../node_modules/pouchdb/node_modules/uuid/wrapper.mjs (vendor.js?**WB_REVISION**=2bee42c9f31943956de3e2e5502f26e8:3294)
at **webpack_require** (app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:260)
at fn (app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:555)
at eval (index-browser.es.js:7)
at Module../node_modules/pouchdb/lib/index-browser.es.js (vendor.js?**WB_REVISION**=2bee42c9f31943956de3e2e5502f26e8:2829)
at **webpack_require** (app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:260)
at fn (app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:555)
at eval (index.js:8)
at Module../src/store/index.js (app.js?**WB_REVISION**=323d436e86b70c38d80f7c79565259c1:107)

If i remove the import the error goes away.

Thanks

Comment: I am using Quasar v3.1.0, Pouchdb has worked on another app with Quasar v2.2.10

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution... facing the same problem. Quasar v3.1.9.

Comment: It has been a while and not sure what fixed it. I am now using < import PouchDB from "pouchdb-browser"; >  instead and is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
For me downgrading the pouchdb library from version 7.2.2 to 7.1.1 solved this problem